# Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'component["isMobxInjector"]') in react native app

Tags: react-native, mobx-react

I am facing this issue suddenly in my react native app. Actually there are two errors, when i start app.

First error

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'component["isMobxInjector"]')

Second error is

> Invariant Violation Houzez has not been registered. This can happen if
> Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it, and restart it in the current project.
> A module failed to load due to an error and AppRegistry.registerComponent wasn't called.

I tried almost all the solutions. My application name is same in all the files like app.json, package.json, appDelegate.mm, and in the mainActivity.java getMainComponentName.

This is my index.js file

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

App.json file

```
{
  "name": "Houzez",
  "displayName": "Houzez"
}
```

Terminal screenshot
[image]

App error screenshot

[image]

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance